# Поиск в БД MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть база данных, в ней есть список адресных строк, например поле `url` с параметром `/goods/page/*/`, подскажите пожалуйста - например открыл я страницу сайта `/goods/page/2/` , как в базе данных найти эту строку?

Получается со стороны сайта в БД отправляется такой запрос:

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `url` LIKE '/news/page/2/'
```

А в БД в таблице `table` есть строка с полем `url` с записью `/goods/page/*/`, вот как его найти?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE INSTR(url, '/news/page/')` попробуйте так

Comment: ``WHERE '/news/page/2/' LIKE REPLACE(`url`,'*','%')``. Если записей в таблице много - лучше хранить шаблоны сразу подготовленными к поиску, с уже выполненным REPLACE().

Comment: Попробовал Вариант с перестановкой от @Akina. Не работает. Данные БД сразу подготовил к поиску, их не много)

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE '".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."' LIKE `url` не работает =)

Comment: Покажите ТОЧНОЕ значение литерала, подставленного в запрос вместо `'/news/page/2/'`, и ТОЧНОЕ значение поля `\`url\``записи, которое должно было бы соответствовать. Полагаю, на самом деле в литерале имеется всякоразное `http://` и прочая ерунда.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/gmvbZ1KcLenjkm

Comment: http://joxi.ru/VrwbayZcOokWlA

Comment: Спасибо, Akina - сделал с Вашей помощью )